# Is it a bug that Java 8's HashMap misbehaves if the keys implement Comparable in a way that isn't consistent with equals?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

I know that since Java 8, if a `HashMap` has enough hash collisions, and the keys implement `Comparable`, it will [use a balanced tree instead of a linked list for the bin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180593/502399).  But from what I can see, the `Comparable` interface [does not require](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) that `compareTo()` be "consistent with `equals()`" (though it is strongly recommended).

Did I miss something?  It seems like the new implementation allows `HashMap` to violate the requirements of the `Map` interface if the keys happen to have a compliant, but non-recommended `Comparable` implementation.

The following JUnit test exposes this behaviour on OpenJDK 8u72:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;

class Foo
        implements Comparable<Foo> // Comment this out to fix the test case
{
    private final int bar;
    private final int baz;

    Foo(int bar, int baz) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // Note that this ignores 'baz'
        return obj instanceof Foo && bar == ((Foo) obj).bar;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int compareTo(Foo o) {
        // Inconsistent with equals(), but seems to obey the requirements of
        // Comparable<Foo>
        return Integer.compare(baz, o.baz);
    }
}

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
            set.add(new Foo(i, 0));
        }

        // This fails if Foo implements Comparable<Foo>
        assertTrue(set.contains(new Foo(64, 1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's not a bug in that it's the known and expected behaviour of the new implementation... note that `TreeMap` has always used order comparisons rather than `equals`, so that has the same issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, but that's why I used a `HashMap` :).  Specifically I worry about code that was intentionally using a `HashMap` (rather than `TreeMap`) in Java 7 because it knew the keys had a non-recommended `Comparable` implementation.  Upgrading to Java 8 could introduce an extremely subtle bug.

Comment: The [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) class is an example of inconsistent with equals that is included with the JDK.

Comment: @jmehrens Indeed.  I haven't been able to reproduce the issue with `BigDecimal` though.  I suspect that if `a.equals(b)` *implies* `a.compareTo(b)` (which *is* true of `BigDecimal`) then you're safe.

Comment: It seems that this indeed *may* be an issue, e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154444/java-8-hash-map-not-working-properly) seemed to refer to a real-world case where the problem appeared. One could argue about whether it's a "bug". It may just be a case where a subtle change in the implementation (for the sake of performance) can have unexpected results in border cases. It's not nice and should be avoided, but this is probably not always possible in the strictest sense...

Comment: Per `HashMap.comparableClassFor` you can make the test case pass by changing `Foo` to implement `Comparable<Object>` instead of `Comparable<Foo>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a *bug* anywhere IMO, in that the code is behaving as the implementor expected - but this is a known result of an unusual `Comparable` implementation. From the [`Comparable` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with `equals`. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with `equals`. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the `equals` method.

Now while this isn't a sorted set or map in the normal sense, there's a clear relationship to the issue.

I agree that it's a possible issue though, and a *really* subtle one, particularly as it'll be hard to reproduce in simple situations. I would update your documentation to draw very strong attention to the fact that your class implements `Comparable` in a way which is inconsistent with `equals`, and specifically refer to this as a potential issue.

Comment: IMO, they should upgrade the documentation just by mentioning that it can happen for any data-structure that may need to use the natural ordering for storing its elements.

Comment: I guess Tavian simply missed this part of the documentation. His entire question is because the documentation of the `compareTo` method is terser and more ambiguous than the class documentation of `Comparable`.

Comment: @DavidS Oh I have definitely read that part of the documentation (and long been aware of the dangers of using a `SortedMap` when the keys have "bad" natural ordering).  But until today I didn't expect any of this to apply to `HashMap`.

Comment: Oh I see then. Too nuanced for me!

Comment: Ah, I found [JDK-8140741](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140741), which indicates that the JDK maintainers consider it only a documentation bug.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Good to see that. This bug report was obviously a follow-up of [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154444/java-8-hash-map-not-working-properly).

Answer (score 6):

First, let’s recall what consistency between `equals` and `compareTo` implies:

([`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Comparable.html))

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be *consistent with equals* if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`.

So one scenario for a natural ordering not being consistent with equals is an ordering where `e1.compareTo(e2)` might return zero despite `e1.equals(e2)` returns `false`. An example would be a case insensitive ordering combined with a case sensitive equality. Another example is `BigDecimal` which has a natural ordering where `new BigDecimal("1.0").compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE)` returns zero but `new BigDecimal("1.0").equals(BigDecimal.ONE)` returns `false`.

Note that the new `HashMap` implementation *handles* these cases. The natural ordering only helps to find a candidate, but a candidate will only considered equal, if the `equals` method returns `true`. This implies that when you have a lot of keys with the same hashcode and being equal according to their natural ordering but not regarding equals, you again end up with a linear search amongst these keys like in the old implementation.

In contrast, your example in an entirely different case. Your `compareTo` implementation may tell that two objects are not equal despite an `equals` test would return `true`. This would never happen with `BigDecimal` or any other practical example of a natural ordering not consistent with equals, I know of.

Your case is not supported by the current implementation, but as you might have noticed, still will only break if the objects also have the same hash code. I doubt that this scenario has a practical relevance. All examples I have seen so far are just constructed *after* learning about the new `HashMap` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is a documented implementation constraint, and a bug in the implementation of `Comparable.`

Comment: Precisely what constraint is being violated?  I read the entire JavaDoc for `Comparable`, what am I missing?

Comment: Indeed: "It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals."