# Java 8 Stream distinct is not working

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is what i am doing:

```
List scores = Stream.concat(oldEntries.stream(), newEntries.stream())
                    .sorted()
                    .distinct()
                    .limit(maxSize)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am expecting a sorted list without any duplicates, but some times there is duplicate in the list.

I have override the hashCode and equals method, I have also observed that these methods are returning the correct value every time. Can any one see what is wrong with my stream?

This is my equals() and hashCode() They are auto generated by IDEA :

```
..
private int userId;
private int levelId;
private int score;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Score score = (Score) o;

    if (userId != score.userId) return false;
    return levelId == score.levelId;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = userId;
    result = 31 * result + levelId;
    return result;
}

public int compareTo(Score other) {

    if (other == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return Integer.compare(other.score, this.score);
    }
}

 ..
```

Comment: Your equals/hashCode is probably not implemented correctly. Include their code in the question.

Comment: @Kayaman they are correct

Comment: Give us full code please

Comment: So you're claiming your code is correct, and `distinct()` is broken?

Comment: @Kayaman I updated the code

Comment: `userId` and `levelId` are `int`?

Comment: @ByeBye yes they are.

Comment: How about the code in `compareTo`?

Comment: @Kayaman I updated the question. When checking for equality I am only intrested in levelID and userId

Comment: @MoienGK that's the problem, your `compareTo` is not consistent with `hashcode/equals`.

Comment: Like Eugene said, your compareTo, hashcode and equals does not match.

Comment: @Eugene I cant see why that is the problem. CompareTo is used for sort, while hashCode and equals() are used for distinct. distinct is not using compareTo. is it?

Comment: No, distinct only uses Object.equals(Object).

Comment: @MoienGK, do you have specific sort of objects which are working wrongly with your code? I wanted to reproduce it, but I cannot

Comment: @MoienGK please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your stream is first ordered according to `compareTo`, i.e. using `score`.

It's then "distinctified" using `equals()`, i.e. using `userId` and `levelId`. According to the javadoc:

> For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for
>   duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter
>   order is preserved.)  For unordered streams, no stability guarantees
>   are made.

Example:

```
score 1, user 2, level 3
score 3, user 2, level 3
score 1, user 3, level 1
```

After sorting...

```
score 1, user 2, level 3
score 1, user 3, level 1
score 3, user 2, level 3
```

Distinct now does nothing, because the elements are not equal according to user/level. This can result in "duplicate" elements, because you're ordering the stream based on one thing, but determining equality by an entirely different thing.

Comment: Is there any documentation of `distinct()` which covers about the `following equals elements are dropped` part?

Comment: You said :"Distinct now does nothing, because the elements are not equal according to user/level." but the elements are equal according to user/level. I am still confused. if distinct is using equals, then it should be able to find the two equal elements

Comment: @MoienGK since the stream is a sorted stream, it's assumed that equal elements follow each other. In the example shown this is not the case, and distinct fails to remove the row with score 3, because it's not equal to the row **before** it.

Comment: Kayaman is right, it seems that for ordered stream distinct use some acceleration to computing and not checking all elements but in pairs. Unfortunately it is not described properly in javadoc of `distinct()`

Comment: @ByeBye what do you mean? It's described quite clearly.

Comment: @Kayaman This is my usecase and I can not change it. is there any other workaround for distinct using streams?

Comment: @MoienGK use distinct first, than sort

Comment: @Kayaman `(for duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter order is preserved.)` for me it means, that always FIRST element  will be preserved, not that it will be checking equality with it neighbours, when in unordered stream it can be random

Comment: @ByeBye thats the point, implementations are free to do this small improvements *assuming* your contracts are correct as far as I can see.

Comment: The effectiveness of the optimization is demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807329/2711488), but note that such problems with a natural order that is inconsistent with `equals` may occur even without that optimization, e.g. when using `distinct()` without `sort()`, as the `HashMap` used behind the scenes uses the natural order to resolve hash collisions ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35164645/2711488))…

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug.

The documentation of `Stream.distinct()` simply says:

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to
> `Object.equals(Object))` of this stream.
>
> For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for
> duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter
> order is preserved.) For unordered streams, no stability guarantees
> are made.

There is no requirement that for ordered streams the equal objects should come right after each other (consecutively). However the implementation seems to assume they do. What the documentation means is that the first occurrence of `user 2, level 3` should be preserved and the second occurrence discarded.

According to the Java bug database the bug exists up to Java 13 and remains unresolved.

### Links

- [Documentation of `Stream.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct())
- [JDK-8223933 Stream.distinct() sometimes allows duplicates when the stream is sorted](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223933) in the JDK Bug System.

Comment: Good find. It's a catch-22 since as an implementation detail it can't *really* be solved by documenting that `hashCode/equals/compareTo` must be consistent.